# How to migrate my ML Model from Staging to Prod without having to retrain the model and without lossing the hyperparameters

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, mlops, deployment

I want to train my ML model in my staging environment and then push the model to production if it performs well. However, I do not want to retrain the model on the entire dataset. I simply want to utilize the new model in production for making predictions based on the training and fine-tuning done in the staging environment.

Please advise on industry best practices and how to save the parameters generated in staging.